# XML Schema validation pattern shall not allow string

Tags: xsd, xsd-validation

I want to allow the alphanumeric characters except for the world "AAAA"
I am using the below regex

1. To allow alphanumeric characters `<xs:pattern value="[A-Za-z0-9]{2,4}"/>`
2. Not to allow AAAA as `<xs:pattern value="[^A]{4}"/>`

But if I combine both it does not work.
Please help

Answer (score 0):

It is not easy to match strings using a regex. The pattern `[^A]{4}` does not mean *not 4 occurrences of A*. It means *4 occurrences of 'not A'*.

I think something like this should work:

```
[A-Za-z0-9]{2,3} | 
[B-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9]{3} | 
[A-Za-z0-9][B-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9]{2} |
[A-Za-z0-9]{2}[B-Za-z0-9][A-Za-z0-9] |
[A-Za-z0-9]{3}[B-Za-z0-9]
```

which means,

- a 2-char or 3-char alphanumeric string or
- a 4 char alphanumeric string with the 1st char not 'A' or
- a 4 char alphanumeric string with the 2nd char not 'A' or
- a 4 char alphanumeric string with the 3rd char not 'A' or
- a 4 char alphanumeric string with the 4th char not 'A'

There might be an easier solution, but I cannot think of it.

Comment: Hi, my requirement is to allow alphanumeric characters <xs:pattern value="[A-Za-z0-9]{2,4}"/>
But not to allow AAAA or aaaa or Aaaa, any combination of A 4 times. AAA or Aaa is allowed

Comment: That sounds like a straightforward modification to the regex that I posted before. Why not try something, and let us know how it goes.